# How does Chaplin.js handle passing a collection to a view?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, chaplinjs

I can create a simple model like so:

```
define(["models/base/model"], function(Model) {
  "use strict";

  var IssueModel = Model.extend({
    defaults:{
      lastName: "Bob",
      firstName: "Doe"
    }
  });
  return IssueModel;
});
```

And then from my controller I can do this:

```
this.model = new IssueModel();
```

And then when I create my view I can pass it my model like so:

```
this.view = new IssueView({model: this.model});
```

Finally, in my template I can successfully get properties on the model by doing this:

```
Hi {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
```

But when I define a collection using `IssueModel` and I try to pass the collection to my view (and not the model like I showed previously) I can't figure out how to reference the models in my Handlebars template:

```
var self = this;
this.collection = new IssueCollection();
this.collection.fetch({
  success: function(collection) {
    self.view = new IssueView({collection: collection});
    console.log(self.collection);
  },
  error: function(collection, error) {
    // The collection could not be retrieved.
  }
});
```

I know `fetch` properly retrieves 5 models from my Parse.com backend because this is what I get on the console:

[image: Console output for collection]

My question is this. I know Chaplin.js uses `getTemplateData`, but when I pass a model I don't have to do anything special in order to reference the properties in my view. How would I reference, specifically iterate, over the collection I passed to my view in my Handlebars template?

```
{{#each [Model in the collection I passed to the view]}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaplin will render a collection using a [CollectionView](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/blob/master/docs/chaplin.collection_view.md), it's basicly an extention of a normal view that listens for changes in your collection and adds/removes subviews accordingly.

```
this.view = new IssueCollectionView({collection: this.collection});
```

Also there is no need to wait for success call when using a collection view since it will automaticly render every child item when data is added.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info on CollectView's automatically updating. I didn't realize that. I asked this question and realized later the answer was on the Chaplin documentation site but the sidebar wasn't working so I hadn't seen the docs regarding CollectionViews. Thanks anyway!